# How to encode a URL using Asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, encoding

I have the following line of aspx link that I would like to encode:

```
 Response.Redirect("countriesAttractions.aspx?=");
```

I have tried the following method:

```
 Response.Redirect(Encoder.UrlPathEncode("countriesAttractions.aspx?="));
```

This is another method that I tried:

```
    var encoded = Uri.EscapeUriString("countriesAttractions.aspx?=");
    Response.Redirect(encoded);
```

Both redirects to the page without the URL being encoded:

```
http://localhost:52595/countriesAttractions?=
```

I tried this third method:

```
 Response.Redirect(Server.UrlEncode("countriesAttractions.aspx?="));
```

This time the url itself gets encoded:

```
http://localhost:52595/countriesAttractions.aspx%3F%3D
```

However I get an error from the UI saying:

```
HTTP Error 404.0 Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or 
is temporarily unavailable.
Most likely causes:
-The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server.
-The URL contains a typographical error.
-A custom filter or module, such as URLScan, restricts access to the file.
```

Also, I would like to encode another kind of URL that involves parsing of session strings:

```
Response.Redirect("specificServices.aspx?service=" + 
Session["service"].ToString().Trim() + "&price=" + 
Session["price"].ToString().Trim()));
```

The method I tried to include the encoding method into the code above:

```
Response.Redirect(Server.UrlEncode("specificServices.aspx?service=" + 
Session["service"].ToString().Trim() + "&price=" + 
Session["price"].ToString().Trim()));
```

The above encoding method I used displayed the same kind of results I received with my previous Server URL encode methods. I am not sure on how I can encode url the correct way without getting errors.

As well as encoding URL with CommandArgument:

```
Response.Redirect("specificAttractions.aspx?attraction=" + 
e.CommandArgument);
```

I have tried the following encoding:

```
Response.Redirect("specificAttractions.aspx?attraction=" + 
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument)));
```

But it did not work.

Is there any way that I can encode the url without receiving this kind of error?
I would like the output to be something like my second result but I want to see the page itself and not the error page.

I have tried other methods I found on stackoverflow such as self-coded methods but those did not work either.
I am using AntiXSS class library in this case for the methods I tried, so it would be great if I can get solutions using AntiXSS library. 
I need to encode URL as part of my school project so it would be great if I can get solutions. Thank you.

Comment: You're question doesn't make much sense. We don't encode the URL, we only encode the parameters of the URL. So the only time we encode a complete URL is when it is passed as a parameter of anther URL. Perhaps you should explain what you're trying to do, so we can help you find the best way to do it.

Comment: Ok sorry I didn't know that URL cannot be encoded, I read from my lecture notes that it can be encoded. What I am trying to achieve is to encode the PARAMETERS that are being passed through a URL. Such as the url with my session parsing and command argument, is there any way where I can encode them within my URL? @RacilHilan

Comment: Yes there is. HttpUtility.UrlEncode method. It accepts a string and returns the encoded version. So you can call it once per parameter. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Can you write out an example on how I can use it? can perhaps use one of the urls i provided in my question to illustrate how I could have done it the correct way. the link you provided is quite vague and does not provide any examples. I used that method before but it did not encode my url. @ADyson

Comment: I tried the method you suggested, I got the same error page. @ADyson

Comment: Did you check (e.g. via your debug mode) that the encoded parameters look as you're expecting? Give an actual real example of a) a URL you want to call, b) the parameter data you input to the UrlEncode method, c) the output you got from the method, d) how you appended that to the URL, and e) how you then used that URL to make a request. We need to see the whole process from beginning to end, because that error doesn't happen until you put the URL together and make a request to it. There could be another reason for your problem, as well.

Comment: Based just on your last piece of code, you could do something like `Response.Redirect("specificAttractions.aspx?attraction=" + 
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument)));`. You could also try UrlPathEncode instead as mentioned in that documentation page

Comment: I have already included everything you mentioned from a) to e) in my question. I tried out the example you gave and I got this output: 
 localhost:52595/viewAttractions?country=Bora%20Bora%2C%20French%20Polynesia but this does not look like it's been encoded except for '%2C' being added in. the %20 has already been there without me adding any encoding method to my url @ADyson

Comment: "this does not look like it's been encoded except for '%2C' being added in." What else did you expect, exactly? Nothing else in there _needs_ encoding for use as a URL. And actually you didn't include point b) because we can't see what the original parameter data was. i.e. what is the output of `Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument)` - the thing we are encoding?

Comment: I expected something like this: %3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A52595%2FviewAttractions%3Fcountry%3DBora%2520Bora%2520French%2520Polynesia. I got this output from an online encoder conversion. Or at this this: localhost:52595/countriesAttractions.aspx%3F%3D  @ADyson

Comment: `%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A52595%2FviewAttractions%3Fcountry%3DBor‌​a%2520Bora%2520Frenc‌​h%2520Polynesia`....that you might get if you tried to encode the _whole URL_ and not just the _parameter_, I don't know. But then again, that output is not a valid URL, so I guess the encoder would be smart enough not to do that. It's not clear why you would want to achieve such a string? It's not very useful. And you still haven't given me your original string

Comment: You can see my point b)  sample url parameter from the one I used with session. That is the original data parameter. To see the original data parameter just simply exclude the encoding method I added in for my other urls. the output i got was %20 in between the parameters == not encoded at all @ADyson

Comment: I want to achieve an encoded URL because my responsibility in my school project is to encode URL? I only resorted to stackoverflow after days of trying out various methods from microsoft website and other people's answers from stackoverflow @ADyson

Comment: " 
You can see my point b) sample url parameter from the one I used with session" ???? There are 3 different separate examples in your question. 1 is using `countriesAttractions.aspx?=`. 2 is `Response.Redirect("specificServices.aspx?service=" + 
Session["service"].ToString().Trim() + "&price=" + 
Session["price"].ToString().Trim()));` for which you never show what any of the session _values_ are. 3 is using `Response.Redirect("specificAttractions.aspx?attraction=" + 
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument)));`

Comment: Again in that one I cannot see what  the _value_ of `Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument))` is. I'm going to _guess_ it was `Bora Bora, French Polynesia` but it would be trivial for _you_ to confirm it instead of me reverse-engineering it. For the others I cannot guess the values because there is nothing in the question or comments which gives any clue to it.

Comment: So let's make this clearer. Pick _one_ example which you want to focus on, then we know what we're working on. Second "my school project is to encode URL"...you don't need to encode a whole URL, you only need to encode the parts which are not otherwise valid in a URL string. Usually this is the contents of the parameters, because they are not predictable. There's no reason to encode the `http://` etc parts, the browser already knows what to do with them. What is the exact question asked by your school project? I assume the purpose is to produce a _valid_ URL? If so, just encode the parameters.

Comment: P.S. Here's a very simple example of the effects of using the UrlEncode and URLPathEncode methods on a parameter, or on a whole URL: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gqFsdK . You can paste each of the results into your browser and see which ones work properly and which don't. Then maybe you can understand what a valid URL looks like. (P.S. when pasting into modern browsers, many of them will URL-encode automatically for you, if your parameter is not valid - so you'll find the first output works too, but if you tried to call it via some C# code for instance, it would fail).

Comment: The session values are dynamic and taken from the database itself thats why i did not put in their values. The command argument is Bind("countries") where "countries" is the name of a column from a table in the database. This was added in the asp.net page of my project. again the countries selected from gridview (i implemented my command argument in gridview) is dynamic so I did not hardcode the exact country name.

Comment: My school project did not ask any question but rather it is a _project_ so i am supposed to produce something and my part is to encode URL. Sorry if i made you sound confused as I have never done encoding before in my life and didn't know the first few characters of the localhost cannot be encoded.

Comment: As for the fiddle example you provided I would like to ask if it works with Response.Redirect instead of Console.Write since I am creating a website. And does that mean that I would have to do hardcode that exact same method if I have let's say, 10 countries? and will the output display an error in the webpage as well.

Comment: "The session values are dynamic and taken from the database itself thats why i did not put in their values. " So what? You're missing the point. We still need sample data in order to answer the question. Seeing the output without the input is an incomplete example. We don't need all the possible values, just something which demonstrates the problem in full. The question is about URL-encoding some values, so we need to see those values. How they got there (from session, gridview etc) is entirely irrelevant to the issue at hand. A hard-coded string would show the issue better.

Comment: And yes the example would work with Response.Redirect the same as Console.WriteLine. Why? Because both methods accept a string as input. a URL is a string. This is a key abstraction concept you need to get hold of - effectively it's the same as the point I've made above. What you're passing the string to is not the issue, using Console.WriteLine was just a way to show it to you, just one of many possible methods of outputting it. The point was to demonstrate the string that was produced.

Comment: "And does that mean that I would have to do hardcode that exact same method if I have let's say, 10 countries? and will the output display an error in the webpage as well. " I really am not sure what you mean by this. If you want to encode some parameters then you need the URLEncode method yes. You can pass whatever _string_ to it you like, from wherever you want to get it from. You can then use the _string_ you get from the output wherever and however you like, it's up to you.

Comment: my codes have already been configured to retrieve values from the database, I dont want to mess up my codes lest my codes do not work again. what I put in my question is exactly what my codes are in my project file. i was asking if the sample codes you provided works for dynamic codes or only static codes, and if your sample codes work will they produce the error i am getting right now @ADyson

Comment: "i was asking if the sample codes you provided works for dynamic codes or only static codes". It works with _values_ contained in _string variables_. As I already explained, whether the values are static (hard-coded into your C# e.g. `string parm = "xyz";`) or dynamic (fetched from a another place e.g. `string parm = Session["someField"].toString();` is irrelevant. Try to see the encoding issue as a single piece of functionality in isolation, with a defined input (a string) and a defined output (a string). Where the values come from doesn't matter, as long as they're strings.

Comment: " if your sample codes work will they produce the error i am getting right now". Well the error if you've got is a 404 Not Found, that simply means the URL you tried to visit doesn't exist. I can't tell you whether your URLs exist or not, I have no idea about your application's structure. All you can do is check what value comes back from your encoding, check it's encoded correctly. A _valid_ URL is simply a string in the correct format of a URL. It is not the same as a URL which actually _exists_. A URL may be valid but not exist if you try to use it, or may be valid and really exist.

Comment: okay thanks for your explanation. i am very certain that my url _exists_ , i can redirect to the page perfectly fine without the encoding method. But once i added in the encoding method it shows the error page. @ADyson

Comment: Ok so show me _exactly_ an example of 1) The URL (including parameters) which works when you redirect it without encoding 2) The code you ran to do the encoding, 3) the URL (including parameters) which was the result of the encoding operation, and which produced the error.

Comment: By the way I tried one of the encoding methods in your fiddle example and it worked, thanks so much. Maybe you can repost the link to the fiddle as an actual answer instead so that I can rate it. Once again thanks so much for your detailed explanation to help me understand what is considered a valid encoded URL. @ADyson

Comment: @depressedGirl No problem. Glad you got something which works. I have added an answer which I hope is satisfactory as a summary of our discussion :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `UrlEncode` or `UrlPathEncode` methods from the HttpUtility class to achieve what you need. See documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx

It's important to understand however, that you should not need to encode the whole URL string. It's only the *parameter values* - which may contain arbitrary data and characters which aren't valid in a URL - that you need to encode.

To explain this concept, run the following in a simple .NET console application:

```
string url = "https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=";
//string url = "http://localhost:52595/specificAttractions.aspx?country=";
string parm = "Bora Bora, French Polynesia";
Console.WriteLine(url + parm);
Console.WriteLine(url + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(parm), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
Console.WriteLine(url + HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(parm), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
Console.WriteLine(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url + parm), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

You'll get the following output:

```
https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Bora Bora, French Polynesia
https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Bora+Bora%2c+French+Polynesia
https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Bora%20Bora,%20French%20Polynesia
https%3a%2f%2fwww.google.co.uk%2fsearch%3fq%3dBora+Bora%2c+French+Polynesia
```

By pasting these into a browser and trying to use them, you'll soon see what is a valid URL and what is not.

(N.B. when pasting into modern browsers, many of them will URL-encode automatically for you, if your parameter is not valid - so you'll find the first output works too, but if you tried to call it via some C# code for instance, it would fail.)

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gqFsdK

You can of course alter the values you input to anything you like. They can be hard-coded strings, or the result of some other code which returns a string (e.g. fetching from the session, or a database, or a UI element, or anywhere else).

N.B. It's also useful to clarify that a *valid* URL is simply a string in the correct format of a URL. It is not the same as a URL which actually *exists*. A URL may be valid but not exist if you try to use it, or may be valid and really exist.

Comment: By the way, I have an additional question to ask. I have managed to encode the following line of URL with its session parameters successfully.  Response.Redirect("specificServices.aspx?service=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Session["service"].ToString().Trim(),Encoding.UTF8) + "&price="+ HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Session["price"].ToString().Trim(),Encoding.UTF8)); However, whenever i try to encode the line "&price=", my datalist output in the redirected page would not be shown. Do you happen to know why? @ADyson

Comment: In short, no I don't, mainly because I can't see what exact data you passed in as the "price" parameter, or what your other page does and how it tries to use the parameter, or what relationship that has to your datalist. I can't read your project, your runtime data, your screen, or your mind. And if you have another question, you need to create another question on StackOverflow and include all the necessary detail (including the information I've just described. The contents of your mind are optional :-) ). If you comment here linking to your new question, I can take a look at it. Thanks.

Comment: ohh i see it's fine then, thanks so much. I'm using another encode method for that line which does not affect my datalist. @ADyson